# Using PHP to generate an XML file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I currently have a PHP script which when ran outputs an XML file (however as feed.php not feed.xml) I have been told to add this to my .htaccess and it should fix it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
```

However for some reason that isn't working.

What I'd ideally like the script to do - when ran is to generate a feed.xml file with the output of its contents, rather than just outputting the contents on the php page.

Here is my code:

```
<?PHP
 include("../config.php");
 #// Timetable Clearup Variabls
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);
$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);
$yesterdayd = date('F jS, Y', time()-86400);

    //SET XML HEADER
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //CONSTRUCT RSS FEED HEADERS
    $output = '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= "<title>Timetable - {$yesterdayd} </title>";
    $output .= '<description>Timetable.</description>';
    $output .= '<link>http://site.com/</link>';
 ###   $output .= '<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>';
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //BODY OF RSS FEED
   $output .= '<item>';
     $output .= "<description><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></description>";
   $output .= '</item> ';
 }
    //CLOSE RSS FEED
   $output .= '</channel>';
   $output .= '</rss>';

    //SEND COMPLETE RSS FEED TO BROWSER
    echo($output);

?>
```

Comment: so if you open this page in the browser it is not giving the xml content, only just giving the php code as it is.... is it so?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest not adding .xml in .htaccess to be processed using PHP compiler.
Rather use **mod_rewrite** to redirect requests to .xml files to php script.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ /rss_feed.php [L,QSA]
```